# are empty blocks scanned during query execution

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a huge table and there has been lots of updates and deletes to it, now I run vacuum analyze on the table. All the records/pages which got marked as available for subsequent operations, will they be scanned during query operations?

What I am trying to ask is for a bloated table, when vacuum is run, does it only help in reclaiming the space for later operations (since vacuum full only reclaims space back to OS) or will it also help in avoiding IO on the pages which are say empty? And obviously it has to scan the pages which are partially filled and partially had dead records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequential scan will also read empty pages. An index scan will avoid empty pages, but it may access more table and index pages. Index scans for a single row are not affected.

You also waste RAM with a bloated table, since your cache will also contain less actual data.